# why Java final variables cannot be assigned a value in the setter method?

Tags: java, final

Non-static final variables can be assigned a value only once.

But why this assignment can happen only either within a declaration or in the constructor?

Comment: Because there is no way to guarantee that the method it is assigned in only gets called once.

Comment: Nor can it be guaranteed that the method it is assigned in would be called before the field is accessed by any other code.

Comment: So there is no way to make a variable "initializable" only once (e.g., a setter would block if variable was already assigned before) solely with java syntax? I thought final might work this way but now I see it's not.

Answer (score 3):

A final variable is defined to be immutable i.e., the value assigned to it will be the one and only for that variable x. As one can read from the JLS([§4.12.4.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4))

> A variable can be declared final. A final variable may only be
> assigned to once.

Now the constructor is just like any other method, except that it is the one that gets executed first when an object (non-static) is created from the class.

Hence, final variables can be assigned through constructors.

For example take the following code:

```
public class Test {

    public final int x;

    public Test(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

Compiler accepts this invocation because it is guaranteed that for that particular object its class's constructor gets invoked first and doesn't invoked again (i.e. constructor gets invoked one and only one time during the entire lifetime of object.)

However following code throws error: `Non-static field 'x' cannot be referenced from a static context`

```
public class Test {

    public final int x;

    static {
        x = 5;
    }

    public Test(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

Since x is not a static field, it cannot be initiated within a static block.

This code would also throw error: `Cannot assign a value to final variable 'x'`

```
public class Test {

    public final int x;
    
    public Test(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

That is because it is not guaranteed for this object, that the method `setX` would run first and only once. The programmer could call this method multiple times. Hence, the compiler throws an error.

> So there is no way to make a variable "initializable" only once (e.g.,
> a setter would block if variable was already assigned before) solely
> with java syntax? I thought final might work this way but now I see
> it's not.

For your question, you could simply make a variable private and add the condition to the setter method to add value only if variable is null.

For example:

```
public class Test {

    private Integer x;

    public Test() {
    }

    public Test(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        if (null == this.x) this.x = x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test y = new Test(5);
        System.out.println(y.x);

        y.setX(20);
        System.out.println(y.x);
    }
}
```

This is **not thread safe** by the way. I just added a simple example.

Answer (score 2):

### What does the keyword `final` mean in Java?

1. When used in a class declaration, it means that the class cannot be extended.
2. When used in a method, it means that the method cannot be overridden.
3. When used in a method parameter, it means the value of such parameter cannot be changed inside the method. (local constant)
4. When used in a class field ("variable), it means that it is a global **constant**.

Values for constants must be resolved at compile time. And, as the word implies, constants fields cannot change value. Therefore, the compiler does not allow the value to be set from a setter (mutator) method.

Contrary to what many believe, for a field to be constant, it does not have to be declared `static` and `final`. That said, since the value of a constant cannot be changed, each class instance will share the same value. Therefore, explicitly making them `static` reenforces this notion.

There is a fifth use of the keyword `final` and this is when used when local variables are declared. This is a more lengthy explanation.

### What happens when you compile code?

I updated my answer because I think part of the problem is that some developers don't quite understand what happens when the code is compiled. As I mentioned before, constant values are resolved at **COMPILE TIME**. To understand this concept, consider the following example:

```
public class MyClass {
   private final double PI = 3.14159;
   // rest of class left out intentionally
}
```

If I compile this class on my laptop and then I deploy the code to some remote server, how does the server know that the global constant field `PI` has an assigned value of 3.14159? This is because when I compile this code, this value gets packaged with the byte code. The class constructor doesn't come into play at all in this case. HOWEVER, if the constant field is initialized to its DEFAULT value, then permanent (constant) value may be assigned via the constructor

```
public class MyClass {
   private final double PI; // default value of 0.0
   public MyClass(double value) {
      PI = value;
   }
// rest of code omitted intentionally
}
```

Here's where declaring a constant as `static` makes a difference. If a constant is also `static`, you can't do the above because calling a constructor implies that you can have multiple instances of `MyClass` and each instance could set a different value. This is clearly a violation of what a `static` member is. So, if you MUST declare a field as both `static` and `final`, understand that you cannot assign a value using this second approach. Only the first one I showed is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

**Final Stop's a Variable’s Reassignment**

a short simple answer:

Use the keyword final when you want the compiler to prevent a variable from being re-assigned to a different object.

Whether the variable is a static variable, member variable, local variable, or argument/parameter variable, the effect is entirely the same.

Hope this helps friend =)
#StaySafe